# Nginx unknown directive "proxy_pass"

Tags: nginx

I'm having a problem with nginx configuration.

When I set the configuration like this:

```
 server {
         server_name redmine;
        listen       80;

        location / {
           proxy_pass http://172.16.0.70:33000;
        }
}
```

I get this error nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "proxy_pass".

My nginx version is nginx/1.8.0.

Someone know what i'm missing or what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that module `ngx_http_proxy_module` is not installed

Run `nginx -V` to view how nginx is configured. If it is configured with option `--without-http_proxy_module` than nginx doesn't have proxy module and should be recompiled.

Comment: Well this is probably the reason for the problem, but how to fix it?

Comment: try $ sudo apt-get install nginx-extras